# Why do connections persist when I undeploy a webapp using the Tomcat 7 JDBC connection pool?

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, tomcat7

I've got a minimal Spring webapp deployed to Tomcat 7.0.22 - it consists of a couple of pages, a controller, a service, and a DAO which has one method that runs a SELECT query.

The webapp is configured to use the new [Tomcat JDBC connection pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) - here is the resource configuration in the webapp's context.xml:

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/myDB"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@blah blah"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          maxActive="15"
          initialSize="5"
          maxWait="40000"
          validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
          logAbandoned="false"
          username="user"
          password="pass"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          validationInterval="30000"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000" />
```

When I deploy the webapp I see 5 connections appear (querying v$session from SQL Developer).  When I undeploy the webapp the connections persist (in state WAITING).  Each time I redeploy my webapp, 5 new connections show up.

It appears the pool is still hanging around - and the "Find Leaks" button on Tomcat's manager app tells me the app is leaking memory.

How do I get rid of the pool when the webapp is undeployed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was self-inflicted (as most are). My data source was configured in my webapp's web.xml and I was referencing it via JNDI.  I now create my data source as shown in the Spring reference doc ([section 13.3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-datasource)) and the `destroy` method takes care of closing the data source and pool.

If I'd been required to stick with a JNDI data source I would have had to close out the data source in a class that implements `ServletContextListener`, in the `contextDestroyed` method.

Answer (score 2):

This is a behaviour reported in Apache Tomcat bugzilla, Reference:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25060

It has been corrected from Tomcat 7.0.11. Which version of Tomcat have you been using ?

If you use create the datasource as described in the Spring reference at"application level", you would a little overhead when it comes to administration tasks if you have a lot of applications and many servers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I could not use spring so I used a [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.html#close%28%29) to close a Tomcat Datasource. This API provides you with functionality not yet implemented JDK DataSource interface.

```
DataSourceProxy myDataSource = (DataSourceProxy) myDataSource;
myDataSource.close();
```

- Also using factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" and a ServletListener contextDestroyed method.