# tomcat 7 ignoring my context.xml

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, server.xml, context.xml

I hope this is something stupid. But I've been staring at it way too long.

I am upgrading to Tomcat 7 (from 6) on Linux and it's ignoring my context.xml file. If I include the Context (datasource) in the server.xml, it work fine. But I would like to finally get that stuff out of the server.xml.

I have Tomcat 7 running in Windows/Eclipse with the separated context and it works fine.

I have tried the Host copyXML parameter. Even if it does copy the context.xml, it won't use it... unless I include it within the Host in the server.xml. When it fails, it complains that it can't get my MySQL connection: "Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid"

I'm sure the rest of the config is fine since it works when I paste it into the server.xml...

Could someone please point out what I am missing? It's not supposed to be this difficult. Thanks!

BTW: It's plain Tomcat7 (not an rpm), JDK-7u11, on CentOS 5.9 (64).

Locations:

```
/var/webapps/shop1
    query.jsp
/var/webapps/shop1/META-INF
    context.xml
```

within server.xml:

```
<Host name="dev3.domain.net" appBase="/var/webapps" 
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Context docBase="shop1" path="" reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/shop1db" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
            maxActive="50" maxIdle="25" maxWait="10000"
            username="user" password="pass"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/shop1"
            logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    />
</Context>
```

within web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.dataSource</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc/shop1db</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: If you use MySQL then maybe this example from the official Tomcat documentaion will help you: [MySQL DBCP Example](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example). By the way the default port for MySQL is **3306**, i.e. it should be `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop1"`, of course if you haven't changed it

Comment: Yes... I had the port there before. Same result though. I think there has to be a setting related to reading the context.xml file. If I set copyXML to true, then it does copy and rename it correctly. So it knows it's there. It just won't do anything with it. Again, if I include the context.xml text in the Host in the server.xml, then it works just fine. But that practice is not ideal...

Comment: I can always go back to that. But this was my opportunity to do it right...

Comment: Actually according to the official Tomcat docs related to [The Context container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) (quote): "**It is NOT recommended to place <Context> elements directly in the server.xml file**. This is because it makes modifying the Context configuration more invasive since the main conf/server.xml file cannot be reloaded without restarting Tomcat." So you are right about not wanting to include context in server.xml

Comment: Also **are you sure** you need `docBase` and `path` attributes in `Context` element (just in case here is the description: [Context attributes](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Attributes))? Maybe trying without them will help. I usually just include custom _context.xml_ without `docBase` or `path` attributes under _META-INF_ in the form like I described in one of my questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13631242/814702. Works like a charm. Of course, maybe YOU have a reason to include those attributes. I just never needed that.

Comment: Also have configured _web.xml_ accordingly like it is described in [MySQL DBCP Example](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example) (see `3. web.xml configuration`)? You just need to experiment. Sorry, if my suggestion didn't help you.

Comment: Tried just <Context> in context.xml but same problem. I added my web.xml above. Again, all this works if I stick it in the server.xml. Also, I added dummy parameters on both the server.xml context as in the context.xml. Tomcat complained about both so I know now it is actually reading both files. I just read something that commons-dbcp is getting old and there is a better tomcat-dbcp. Holding my breath. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to be clear, I have the tomcat-dbcp etc, mysql-connector, all in the tomcat/lib. None of the DB stuff is in the WEB-INF/lib. I just don't get it.

Comment: Using factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" gave the same result... Ugh.

Comment: Sorry, it really is weird. I also used new Tomcat JDBC Pool - no problems whatsoever ...

Comment: Do you need the <Context> element inside <HOST> ? We don't use it, and Tomcat picks up META-INF/context.xml without needing to be told anything extra.

Comment: Without the Context in the Host, how does it determine the Path? i.e. / vs /somedir ? Interesting. I'll try that...

Comment: @PrecisionPete were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: No. I've just been living with it...

Comment: @PrecisionPete Ok. Thats very sad ! I am also having hard time finding the cause of this error.

Comment: Same problem for me using postgres. Would also be desirable to anly need to include the web app and the server.xml into SVN,

Comment: Same problem for me using postgres. Would also be desirable to only need to include into SVN, the web app's context.xml instead of the Server config file server.xml

Answer (score 0):

Do any of these changes work?…

**1:** in your `web.xml` snippet, replace `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.dataSource` with just `javax.sql.dataSource`

**2:** replace your `web.xml` snippet completely (i.e. the entire `context-param` section) with:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/shop1db</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

3: ensure that you really do have a MySQL connector (jar?) available to your web app—e.g. in `WEB-INF/lib`

Hope something there might help…

… and given this question is a couple of months old now, and should you have resolved it yourself in the meantime, please comment here with the fix that worked for you! :-P