# Tomcat JDBC connection pool issue: "Statement is closed"

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a server application that uses the Tomcat JDBC connection pool.

This is the code I use to create the DataSource:

```
PoolProperties connProperties = new PoolProperties();
connProperties.setUrl(resources.getProperty("db.url"));
connProperties.setDriverClassName(resources.getProperty("db.driver"));
connProperties.setUsername(resources.getProperty("db.user"));
connProperties.setPassword(resources.getProperty("db.password"));
connProperties.setJmxEnabled(true);
connProperties.setTestWhileIdle(false);
connProperties.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
connProperties.setTestOnReturn(false);
connProperties.setValidationInterval(30000);
connProperties.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
connProperties.setMaxActive(500);
connProperties.setInitialSize(50);
connProperties.setMaxWait(10000);
connProperties.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
connProperties.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(60000);
connProperties.setSuspectTimeout(60);
connProperties.setMaxIdle(50);
connProperties.setMinIdle(10);
connProperties.setLogAbandoned(false);
connProperties.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
connProperties.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");

dataSource = new DataSource();
dataSource.setPoolProperties(connProperties);
```

Then I have a method to get a connection from the pool

```
protected Connection getDbConnection() throws Exception
{
    dbConn = dataSource.getConnection();
    return dbConn;
}
```

And every time I want to execute a statement I call this code:

```
protected CallableStatement executeCSqlQuery(String sql) throws Exception
{
    CallableStatement cstmt;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        cstmt = getDbConnection().prepareCall(sql);     
        cstmt.execute();            
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }

    return cstmt;
}
```

And this is an example of a call to the previous code:

```
try {
    cstmt = dbConnection.executeCSqlQuery(query);
    rs = cstmt.getResultSet();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do smething
} finally {
    try {
        if (cstmt != null) {
            cstmt.close();
        }
        dbConnection.shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something
    }
}

public void shutdown() {
    if (this.dbConn != null) 
        this.dbConn.close();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that every now and then, I'm getting an exception "Statement is closed" when I execute a call in a Thread every X seconds. 
I'm not sure why this happens. I'm thinking that it could be a driver bug or something failing with the connection to the database (that runs in a different server).

I'm out of ideas. What am I missing?

Should I use *c3p0* connection pool instead?

Comment: what does `dbConnection.shutdown();` do?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that one: if (this.dbConn != null) this.dbConn.close();

Comment: In your last block of code I don't think you should be calling shutdown().  The connection pool might try and use it again.  The connection pool will shutdown() a connection when it feels necessary.

Comment: So you mean i should only close the statement and leave the connection open? What i read here is the opposite:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938517/closing-jdbc-connections-in-pool

Comment: You definitely want to call `connection.close()` because this is how you mark that it's no longer in use and it can be recycled. As it's bean explained in the link above, the framework will then decide whether to close it or return it to the pool according to its settings.

Comment: As a side note: common practice for the web applications deployed on some Servlet container (like Tomcat) or Application Server (like GlassFish, WebLogic, WebSphere etc) is to configure JDBC connection pooling in *context.xml* file placed under *META-INF* folder. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595794/jdbc-connection-pool-runs-out-of-connections-when-context-reload-true-is-enabl). And also [The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) is absolutely OK to use (of course it's a matter of preference and you can choose c3p0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the bounty to help out Reznik but I ended up figuring out what the problem was by looking at his code.

The problem is that every time a new connection is fetched from the pool in

```
protected Connection getDbConnection() throws Exception
{
    dbConn = dataSource.getConnection();
    return dbConn;
}
```

the object `dbConn` is updated to a new connection.

Example:

`T1` invokes `getDbConnection()`

`T2` invokes `getDbConnection()`

`T1` executes the query, processes the `resultSet` and calls `shutdown()`

```
public void shutdown() {
    if (this.dbConn != null) 
        this.dbConn.close();
}
```

Because `T2` updated the object, the connection being used by `T2` will be shutdown by `T1`

`T2` tries to use the connection but it is already closed.

This way, instead of always updating the connection, just return it and then add the extra logic to close the connection that was fetched from the pool.

Comment: Basically 'conn' should not be a member variable, otherwise it isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @EJP +1, it's very important moment. Actually, every method that executes some SQL query should get **its own and NEW** Connection, Statement (or PreparedStatement) and ResultSet, i.e. they should be local variables (declared inside the method). And as soon as the main logic is done,  those resources MUST be closed in the finally block.

Answer (score 2):

I notice two things:

1) `connProperties.setTestOnReturn(false);`
which should be changed to true. Otherwise your connection isn't necessarily valid. And you might not get notified until you receive an invalid Statement.

2) You should ALWAYS **close** your *ResultSet*, *Statement* and *Connection* objects. It does involve a lot of boilerplate, or you could use my [static Close utility method](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html).

Answer (score 1):

1) `protected CallableStatement executeCSqlQuery(String sql) throws Exception` returns the callable statement. If you are trying to use it again after closing it inside the method, you'll probably get that error. All the processing involving that object should be done before closing it.

2) The same method has a `catch(SQLException ){throw e}`. You'd either want to handle the exception there, or if you want to propagate it remove the try-catch

3) I can see in the last piece of code `rs = cstmt.getResultSet();` It is always a good practice to close the resources in the inverse order that they were obtained, as you've read in the post you linked for Peter. So `rs.close(); cstmt.close(); connection.close();`. It's not included in your sample, but if you're returning the ResultSet after closing it, you'll have the same problem described at 1)

Comment: Answering your marks: 1) when executeCSqlQuery returns, right after, is the getResultSet. There's no close() between. 3) the "statement is closed" error happens on the getResultSet(). Which means it never gets it.

Comment: If you get the exception on `cstmt.getResultSet()` it means that the statement was closed by someone else while you were using it. You also said that you are running this inside a thread, so I'd suspect a multithreading synchronization issue

Comment: Being a pool, shouldn't an open statement be used by the thread who opened it? If a 2nd thread comes along and opens another statement, it's a different connection to the pool, right?

Comment: It really depends on how you store and use the objects in your code, like this field `cstmt = dbConnection.executeCSqlQuery(query);`. Can you post the full code, including the thread part?

Comment: All the code executed by a thread is above. The threads execute the last block where it reads "try {
cstmt = dbConnection.executeCSqlQuery(query); (...)"

Comment: I understand that, but it is important to see and understand how you create your objects and how they are shared across the threads