# tomcat jdbc statement is closed with connection pool

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I did the mistake of wrongly categorize the previous question and when i realized the mistake it was too late.

So here's the link to the former question:
[Tomcat JDBC connection pool issue: "Statement is closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538797/tomcat-jdbc-pool-statement-is-closed)

(sorry for the re-post)

Comment: No need of repost. Just update the content in your question.

Comment: @Reznik Please just delete this question, it will save us from having to do it  for you.  Use the menu underneath the question.