# CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, connection-timeout

My Application throws below exception message on production but it does not throw the same exception on stage server.
**

> CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call
>   dm_mobile_pkg.is_user_provisioned(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state
>   [null]; error code [17008]; Closed Connection; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection

**

I doubt that when number of user requests increases so connections also increases which causes insufficient connection to be used.
Please do let me know if you need some more information.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538797/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-issue-statement-is-closed). Is the accepted answer helpful?

Comment: Also [think about timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24295070/232279) ...