# MS SQL JDBC driver create memory leak with JNDI Hikari on Tomcat 9

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, jndi, hikaricp

I am using JNDI + HikariCP on Tomcat 9.0.7 with the following configuration :

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container"
      factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      minimumIdle="5" 
      maximumPoolSize="20"
      connectionTimeout="300000"
      dataSourceClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource"
      dataSource.url="jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=mydb"      
      dataSource.user="fantomas"
      dataSource.password="somepassword" 
      closeMethod="close"
      />
```

When I run tomcat without any of my WAR deployed (just standard installation, nothing more), I have the following WARNING in Catalina log:

```
09-May-2018 10:15:16.971 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [host-manager] appears to have started a thread named [mssql-jdbc-TimeoutTimer-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What is wrong and why there is a leak ? How can I fix it ?

**UPDATE-1**
Custom libraries in ./lib of Tomcat installation are:

```
ms-sql-6.4.0.jre8.jar 
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar 
HikariCP-2.7.8.jar
```

**UPDATE-2**
Same problem also with Hikari 3.1.0 & Tomcat 9.0.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread in question (*mssql-jdbc-TimeoutTimer*) belongs to the MSSQL driver. It shows up when you use HikariCP, but not Tomcat JDBC, because HikariCP *appropriately* uses JDBC timeout APIs for reliability.

This is a known issue with the MSSQL driver, [search for 'mssql-jdbc-TimeoutTimer' here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/JDBC-Survey-Results).

It seems that the timer is started by HikariCP's call to the MSSQL driver implementation of `Connection.isValid()`.  So, you *may* be able to avoid the issue by setting a `connectionTestQuery`, which will disable the use of `isValid()`.

Comment: Thanks, tested with connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1" on Tomcat 9.0.8 and works.

Comment: Can anyone figure out which the actual Github issue is?  Possibly this one, but it's marked as solved.  https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/150

Answer (score 0):

[Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595794/jdbc-connection-pool-runs-out-of-connections-when-context-reload-true-is-enabl/13631242#13631242) with similar leak [reported to hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/642) and it seems that the final solution doesn't use Hikari JNDI factory but Tomcat's Datasource

Try to change the factory to:

```
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
```

**EDIT**

You created a new [issue](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1165) for Hikari

Comment: This will use Tomcat's own database pool instead of Hikari pool. But we want to use Hikari pool because of better performance. Is there some solution with Hikari pool ?

Comment: @kulatamicuda I suggest you open an issue with full details to https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/new

Comment: reported to github as suggested