# Spring to Spring boot migration. Embedded Spring Data source

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

Currently, it has been used Spring Boot application with the custom Data source configuration like this one

**Before**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootAppInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAppInitializer.class);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    basicDataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    basicDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    basicDataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    return basicDataSource;
}
```

**The code above is working**

**After**
(To use an embedded data source cross out DataSourceAutoConfiguration exclusion OR vs)

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootAppInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAppInitializer.class);
    }
}
```

Also, there are two actually the same groups of Properties I'm trying to use to make it work standard one which is used in whole tutorials and the second one - embedded Hikari impl from Spring boot.
the part of *D:\Projects\Octava\Business\src\main\resources\application-businessProduction.properties* file in Business submodule of Octava project

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.data=data-postgresql.sql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/octavadb
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1

duplicated props for HIkari impl
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=classpath:data-postgresql.sql
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/octavadb
spring.datasource.hikari.username=postgres
spring.datasource.hikari.password=1
```

Now, I'm trying to remove custom data source creation and use embedded one. But both groups of properties doesn't work.

Here is the initialization of embedded Hikari data source
[image]

```
2020-05-11 20:35:23.922 ERROR 20064 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54586', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why this approach doesn't work, perhaps any alternatives?

**UPDATE:**

After IntelliJ IDEA has been restarted DataSource is being created but there is a new exception

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-11 21:55:55.599  INFO 12668 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2020-05-11 21:55:55.875 ERROR 12668 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setPersistence' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [octava/config/BusinessHibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/ShardingKey


2020-05-11 21:55:55.906  WARN 12668 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you are trying to do. Your properties show configuration for a postgresql database, which is not embedded. And from your debug breakpoint, it looks like your properties aren't being loaded. If you actually are trying to configure an embedded database (not postgres), then checking the obvious: You have an embedded database (H2, HSQL, Derby, etc) on the runtime classpath, correct? You might want to try clarifying your question if you don't get helpful answers.

Comment: Properties are ok because of it accessible from Environment bean (see the before section);  I'm not trying to use embedded DB at all. Just trying to use Spring Boot OOTB data source bean configuration (DataSource.class) with using only properties. So, the main goal is to remove manual creation of DataSource bean (in my case BasicDataSource imply) nothing more. UPD: restart my Intelij IDEA DataSource began work but with The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally, I've fixed it.

- The main fix was taken from here
  [How to set up datasource with Spring for HikariCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172643/how-to-set-up-datasource-with-spring-for-hikaricp) it was all about dependencies
- also, check this one
  [JDBC connection pool runs out of connections when Context reload="true" is enabled in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595794/jdbc-connection-pool-runs-out-of-connections-when-context-reload-true-is-enabl/13631242#13631242)
  *didn't do it in my case but perhaps will help* close / destroy-methods should be added for old implementations.

Final properties are (**properties with spring.datasource.hikari. prefix was removed**)

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.data=data-postgresql.sql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/octavadb
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1
```

Gradle changes to make it work

```
    compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.7.6') {
        exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
    }
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:4.3.8.Final') {
        //they are pulled in separately elsewhere, to avoid version conflicts
        exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
        exclude group: 'com.zaxxer', module: 'HikariCP'
    }
```